# JavaScript HTML Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

What is my goal: When  I click on a certain word (not in paragraph), I want a speech bubble full of info to appear.

So, I already have this bubble, I've made it using a "class" and CSS 3.

Can I, using some basic JavaScript, make my dream come true? I have no knowledge of JavaScript at all.

Is there a way of somehow putting my "bubble class" into "onclick"?

Thanks in advance.

Everything is an option as long as it works on IE =)

Comment: Hey Leo.. Interesting that you said this as a DREAM. never mind it is easy.Can you use jQuery or you just have to use javascript?

Comment: Is jQuery an option, or plain JavaScript only?

Comment: It might be tougher to achieve for someone who does not know the difference between Java and JS.

Comment: first step into making ur dream come true is post dat code :)

Comment: If you can describe it with words, you can program it in code. Isn't that a dream??

Comment: Everything is an option as long as it works on IE =)

Answer (score 2):

There are many plugings for fulfill your requrement. This is a only a one solution. 
download [bubbletip](http://code.google.com/p/bubbletip/)

You can see a demo [here](http://www.uhleeka.com/blog/2009/11/bubbletip/) and some instruciton too

you really no need to click the word instead just hover is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check out JQuery Tools.  Their page on tooltips has some samples:  http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/dynamic.html

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with JQuery Tools in any way, just found this doing some quick searching based on user's needs.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have several bubbles, you should give each of them a separate id attribute. The following javascript will make the bubble appear:

    `document.getElementById("id_of_the_bubble").style.display = "none";`

The following will make a bubble reappear:

    `document.getElementById("id_of_the_bubble").style.display = "block";`

Note: if you have the bubbles be by default with a different display other than `block`, then you should put it as that display instead of `block`.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap framework

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers